# Gerando duas tags do CheckBox sendo uma hidden no AspNet MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Boa Noite

```
@Html.CheckBox("Agree", new { value = false, @class = "filled-in", @id = "filled-in-box" })
```

Quando gero o CheckBox no AspNet, pelo comando acima, ele está me gerando duas Tags sendo que uma é Hidden, como estou utilizando o materialize css, ele está ficando bugado, jogando o left do CheckBox para -9999, se removo o nó do Hidden o layout fica correto, é possível que não gere essa Tag Input Hidden?

```
 <input class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" name="Agree" value="False" type="checkbox">
 <input name="Agree" value="false" type="hidden">
```

Até o momento, a opção que tive foi criar um método de extensão que remove a tag Hidden

```
public static MvcHtmlString RemoveHiddenTag(this MvcHtmlString pValue) 
{ 
    const string pattern = @"<input name=""[^""]+"" type=""hidden"" value=""false"" />"; 
    string result = Regex.Replace(pValue.ToString(), pattern, ""); 
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(result); 
}
```

Comment: Você pode colocar na sua pergunta a tela destorcida !!!??? e como deveria ficar! Talvez ai o problema seja no css? essa geração das tags é assim mesmo!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic andei pesquisando bastante em fóruns e vi que não é bug, pelo que entendi no AspNet MVC ele gera a Tag Hidden junto com o CheckBox para caso o Flag não esteja marcado ele enviar o false para o Model (Apesar de Remover o Hidden e não ter esse problema), como o projeto usa o Materialize CSS, um CheckBox personalizado e ele que estava ficando bugado quando tinha a Tag Hidden pegava o Left do CheckBox para -9999, para não ter que ficar escrevendo CSS adicionais utilizei a função que escrevi (Atualizado no Post) para remover a Tag Hidden.

Comment: Sim, eu até sei que o Asp.net MVC faz isso, e achei estranho, já utilize materialize e não tenho problemas!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic to começando com a parte de Web agora, sempre trabalhei na parte de Back-End, talvez alguma outra coisa no CSS pode estar influenciando, mas como não tinha muito tempo para procurar solução ou efetuar testes optei por remover o Hidden.